# Python app-level document/record locking (eg. for MongoDB)

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, mongodb

MongoDB does not provide means to lock a document (like `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in RDBMS).

There is a recommended approach to [Isolate Sequence of Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/), which is sometimes called *optimistic locking*, but there are scenarios when this approach seems to be overly complicated or even inefficient (that is why *pessimistic locks* are still in use).

### Task

I am trying to implement generic (can be used with various databases) document (or record) locking at application level. Assuming I have only one application working with collection (or table). And my application is *multi-threaded*.

Usage scenario:

```
with DocumentLock(doc_id):
  # make sure no other thread interferes
  doc=db.doc_collection.find_one(doc_id)
  ... # analyse and update the document
  db.doc_collection.save(doc)
```

### Solution

Here is my DocumentLock class:

```
class DocumentLock(object):

  _lock=RLock() # protects access to _locks dictionary
  _locks=WeakValueDictionary()

  def __init__(self, doc_id):
    self.doc_id=doc_id

  def __enter__(self):
    with self._lock:
      self.lock=self._locks.get(self.doc_id)
      if self.lock is None:
        self._locks[self.doc_id]=self.lock=RLock()
    self.lock.acquire()

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.lock.release()
    self.lock=None # make available for garbage collection
```

So basically I have a dictionary of `RLocks`, one `RLock` per accessed document. I use weak references to get rid of unused locks.

`DocumentLock` can be subclassed for every collection (or table) that needs record locking.

### Question

This all seems to work (although not tested under concurrency) but I am publishing it here for review and advise. Do you see any weaknesses or mistakes in this code? Is there a better approach to do this kind of things in Python?

Answer (score 2):

1. The above code will fail with multiple worker nodes (or processes).
2. To achieve atomic find-and-update, mongodb provides native solution (findOneAndUpdate, findAndModify, updateOne, updateMany).